# Subscription start date should be greater than current date

Tags: paypal, recurring

My online store is Australian based and while setting up recurring profile with paypal I am getting this error.

PayPal gateway has rejected request. Subscription start date should be greater than current date

Comment: Make sure the server data & time is correct, and you have the correct timezone set in System->Configuration->General.

Answer (score 1):

To help debug this you could look into the function `Mage_Payment_Model_Recurring_Profile::setNearestStartDatetime`

```
/**
 * Determine nearest possible profile start date
 *
 * @param Zend_Date $minAllowed
 * @return Mage_Payment_Model_Recurring_Profile
 */
public function setNearestStartDatetime(Zend_Date $minAllowed = null)
{
    // TODO: implement proper logic with invoking payment method instance
    $date = $minAllowed;
    if (!$date || $date->getTimestamp() < time()) {
        $date = new Zend_Date(time());
    }
    $this->setStartDatetime($date->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT));
    return $this;
}
```

As Marius has mentioned in a comment make sure that your sever date and time is correct and you have the correct timezone setup in the system configuration.